# What can make the eclipse debugger to skip a 'while' content to the break of the 'default' of an inner switch?

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, while-loop, switch-statement

Within a java project I have the following code:

```
public static <return> method(<parameters>){
1   <any method call>
2   while( <conditions> ){
3       <any method call>
4       switch(<enum or integer>){
5       case 0:
6       <any method call>
7           break;
8       case 1:
9       <any method call>
10          break;
11      case 3:
12      <any method call>
13          break;
14      default:
15      <any method call>
16          break;
17      }
18   <any method call>
19   }
  }
```

When stepping over with the debugger, the first time I enter the while, it jumps from 2 to 16.

I've been trying to replicate it with stripped out code without success, and to find what piece is responsible for this weird behavior, but and until now, just another weird thing found:

When I declare a dummy variable at 1 AND modify it at 18 (at 3 doesn't work), the behavior is the expected (enter line 3 just after 2)

Edit:

Attached [java file](https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B8_EhCA0YWHCNUd1OHQtM1UyNnc) and 
[disensambled code](https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B8_EhCA0YWHCYWxnRmFUODFBOHc)

Comment: I think we need to see the actual code on this one.

Comment: I am guessing that this is not eclipse's doing but some kind of optimization by `javac`. Can you compile the code and see the `javap` output?

Comment: Add debugging output on the lines you are mentioning. Just log that you are on line 2 for instance. Do this for all lines and observe the log. I bet that the actual lines your code passes through are not the ones that the debugger shows.

Comment: The weird thing is a jump to the 'break' line right before entering the while conditions check, only the first time. Logging on each line provides no new clues. BTW I think this has no effect on execution, but I want to understand what's going on, just in case.